# VBA- Copy specific columns to a sheet from a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

i need some help how to fix my syntax. Whenever i try to run it there is an error saying "subscript out of range"

I need to copy columns ("B:F"),("J"),(N:Q), (S:V) from Sheet("Filtered Data") to a workbook Sheet("February 2018 Tracker (Raw)")

When i deleted the selected columns ("J"),(N:Q), (S:V) the code is working and copying the data from columns B2:F2.

I know there is something wrong with my syntax but i can't figure it out how to correct it. Please help.

Thanks

```
Sub L4toMetrics()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim MainWorkfile As String
Dim OtherWorkfile As String

MainWorkfile = ActiveWorkbook.Name

lRow = Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("February 2018 Tracker (Raw)").Select
    Range("B2:Q2" & lRow).ClearContents
    Range("C1").Select

    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename
    OtherWorkfile = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Sheets("Filtered Data").Select
    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.FilterMode Or _
       ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then _
       ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("B2:F2" & lRw).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Windows(MainWorkfile).Activate
    Sheets("February 2018 Tracker (Raw)").Select
    lstrw = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("B" & lstrw).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False



   Windows(OtherWorkfile).Activate
    Sheets("Filtered Data").Select
    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.FilterMode Or _
       ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then _
       ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("J2" & lRw).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Windows(MainWorkfile).Activate
    Sheets("February 2018 Tracker (Raw)").Select
    lstrw = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("C" & lstrw).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False



   Windows(OtherWorkfile).Activate
    Sheets("Filtered Data").Select
    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.FilterMode Or _
       ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then _
       ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("N2:Q2" & lRw).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Windows(MainWorkfile).Activate
    Sheets("February 2018 Tracker (Raw)").Select
    lstrw = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("D" & lstrw).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False



  Windows(OtherWorkfile).Activate
    Sheets("Filtered Data").Select
    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.FilterMode Or _
       ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then _
       ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("S2:O2" & lRw).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Windows(MainWorkfile).Activate
    Sheets("February 2018 Tracker (Raw)").Select
    lstrw = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("D" & lstrw).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False




    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Shouldnt code lines like `Range("B2:F2" & lRw).Select` be `Range("B2:F" & lRw).Select` ? 2. What line is the error on? 3. Read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: 4. `Range("J2" & lRw).Select
    Selection.Copy` should be `Range("J2:J" & lRw).Copy`

Comment: Hi @Jeeped Range("B2:F2" & 1Rw).select is working fine. The line error is from Range("J2") to Range("S2:O2"). It does not read to copy the selected range.

Comment: **tldr:** There appear to be several rudimentary syntax and typographical errors. Can you get started on those and [edit] your post to include the corrections?

Comment: If 1Rw is 100 then Range("B2:F2" & lRw) refernces B2:F2100 not B2:F100 so **no** it is not 'working fine'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relying too much on the MACRO-Recorder, try the code below to copy>>paste for the first section (columns "B:F").

You be able to implement it for the rest of the columns.

```
Option Explicit

Sub L4toMetrics()

Dim MainWorkfile As Workbook
Dim OtherWorkfile As Workbook
Dim TrackerSht As Worksheet
Dim FilterSht As Worksheet

Dim lRow As Long, lRw As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' set workbook object
Set MainWorkfile = ActiveWorkbook

' set the worksheet object
Set TrackerSht = MainWorkfile.Sheets("February 2018 Tracker (Raw)")
With TrackerSht
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"
    .Range("B2:Q2" & lRow).ClearContents
End With

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

' set the 2nd workbook object
Set OtherWorkfile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)

' set the 2nd worksheet object
Set FilterSht = OtherWorkfile.Sheets("Filtered Data")

With FilterSht
    If .FilterMode Or .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column "C"

    .Range("B2:F" & lRw).Copy ' copy your range
End With

' paste
TrackerSht.Range("B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

' implement it for the rest of your columns...


End Sub
```

Comment: There is an error "object variable or with block variable not set"         
Line item (MainWorkfile = ActiveWorkbook)

Comment: @aicirtap you are right, fixed it now, try the modified code

Comment: @aicirtap do you have any data in the sheet before pasting ?

Comment: Hi @shai rado the data i have in the sheet is the column header only and at the column A there is a formula to determine what division is in the column C, other than that there is no other data at other columns. When i run the code it overlaps the column header which should be started at "B2"

Comment: Thanks Shai i already resolved the issue of overlapping, what i did is i started copying the range from B1:F since they are the same title of the header. Then i deleted (.Range("B2:Q2" & lRow).ClearContents) because whenever i try to run again the code it is pasted from the last row that have a data. I used (Worksheets("February 2018 Tracker (Raw)").Range("B2:S1023").ClearContents) from the start of the syntax. Thanks again